# Pine Script - Plotting with stepline and Multi-Color conditions

Tags: plot, pine-script

Why am I able to change the line color based on conditions for both line or line with breaks, but not with stepline? For some reason when I use stepline as my line option, it ignors the conditions and just goes with the first color. Thoughts?

```
//@version=3 
study("My Script", overlay=true) 

lookback = input(title="Lookback Period", type=integer, defval=9, minval=1) 

HighestHigh = highest(close, lookback)[1] 
LowestLow = lowest(close, lookback)[1] 

highlinecolor = if HighestHigh > HighestHigh[1] 
 green 
else 
 if HighestHigh < HighestHigh[1] 
      red 
 else 
      gray 

lowlinecolor = if LowestLow > LowestLow[1] 
 green 
else 
 if LowestLow < LowestLow[1] 
      red 
 else 
      gray 

plot(HighestHigh, color=highlinecolor, linewidth=2, transp=0, title="Highest high", style=line) 
plot(LowestLow, color=lowlinecolor, linewidth=2, transp=0, title="Lowest Low", style=stepline)
```

Comment: First of all, I assume when you copied your code here, its indentation got somehow messed up. Anyways, this seems to be a bug. Interesting thing is, if you move around with your mouse on the chart, and if you look at the values of your plot functions, you can see that the colors are changing (Find your script name on the chart, and look to the right for the values).

Comment: I cannot use stepline. Says: Undeclared identifier 'stepline':
plot(mySignal, color = plotColor, linewidth = 2, style = stepline, title="signal")